# What is the best way to deal with time math in Perl?

Tags: perl, time

I am running through two large log files and I want to compare timestamps.

I already wrote a Perl script to find the matching log statements, but I need to find the difference in the timestamps.

For example, 15:31:19.430888  minus 15:31:19.427763

Are there any good constructs for dealing with time in Perl? I don't want to deal with time math myself if I can avoid it.

Comment: Spend it learning Python? <ducks>

Comment: http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-6132371.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/lib/DateTime.pm) CPAN module.

eg.

```
my $dt = DateTime->new( 
                      year   => 2009,
                      hour   => 15,
                      minute => 31,
                      second => 19,
                      nanosecond => 430888
);
my $dt2 = DateTime->new( 
                      year   => 2009,
                      hour   => 15,
                      minute => 31,
                      second => 19,
                      nanosecond => 427763
);
my $duration = $dt - $dt2;
```

which will give you a [DateTime::Duration](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/lib/DateTime/Duration.pm) object to retrieve the results from.

Comment: Is there any such construct in the defaul perl lib?  Not in CPAN?

Comment: @windfinder: I don't believe that there is.  Perl comes with a fairly limited set of default libs.

Comment: wordfinder, in case you didn't see below, Time::Piece is in the core libs in the latest Perl.  I don't think that's a good enough reason to use something, in general, but Time::Piece is pretty good.

Answer (score 5):

DateTime is the best, but only if you remember to use the subtract_datetime_absolute method instead of the overloaded minus operator when you do any date math involving subtraction.  This is the only way to get a "stopwatch duration" out of two datetimes, and only the stopwatch duration has ever been useful for the kind of date arithmetic I do.  The DateTime::Duration interface is confusing and misleading, especially when you think you have a stopwatch duration and you don't.

[People mentioned early on how confusing this was going to be](http://marc.info/?l=perl-datetime&m=110451908609630&w=2) but it was never corrected.

The Time::Piece module makes a nice alternative.  I'd have to say that overall it is not as useful as DateTime, but it definitely avoids this kind of confusion.  I prefer DateTime, but just barely.

Comment: Time::Piece also comes with 5.10 for the "I only want core modules" crowd.  Usually a misguided desire, but I thought I'd mention it.